# Learning PSK Modulation and Demodulation - Good Text to Read?

Tags: modulation, reference-request, qpsk, bpsk

Title sums it up. I am curious to see what you all suggest. I'm a newbie and just need some beginner/intermediate material.

Thanks!

Comment: "Modern Digital and Analog Communication Systems" by Lathi and Ding.

Comment: "Digital Communications" by Proakis